# Angular2 loads external Javascript library fails

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying load some external JS libraries for my component. However, some works, some does not. I am not sure if there is a workaround for bootstrap-datatable or I have to modify the JS file?

Here is the error I got:
[Error: Error: Multiple anonymous defines in module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7oU.gif)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

import LeftNavComponent from '../common/left-nav';
import LeftNavHamburgerBtnComponent from '../common/left-nav-hambtn';

import ApprovalsComponent from '../approval/approvals';

@Component({
    selector: 'pc-home',
    styleUrls: ['app/components/home/home.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
    directives: [
        RouterLink,
        RouterOutlet,
        LeftNavComponent,
        LeftNavHamburgerBtnComponent
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/approvals', component: ApprovalsComponent, name: 'Approvals', useAsDefault: true }
])
export default class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    title: string;
    titleIcon: string;
    appVersion: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        System.import('resources/js/datatables/datatables.min.js'); // not working
        System.import('resources/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.js'); // works
        System.import('resources/js/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); // works
        //System.import('node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'); // Enable this if use Chart.js
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.title = 'Approvals';
        this.titleIcon = 'fa-edit';
        this.appVersion = 'v2016.8.1.0';

        if ($(document).width() < 769) {
            $('body').addClass('body-small');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('body-small');
        }

        $(window).bind("resize", function () {
            if ($(this).width() < 769) {
                $('body').addClass('body-small');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('body-small');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to import them via System?
They seem to be jQuery plugins except for Chart.js.

If you load them in the correct order you can access them within your Angular 2 application.

Comment: I do not want to put everything in index.html by using <script>. I want to only load the JS needed for that certain component when the component is used.